# Understanding the radius of convergence for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}k^{-k} x^k$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to understand the convergence radius of

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}k^{-k} x^k$$

We've written the following:

We set $a_n = \binom{2n}{n}n^{-n}$.

Then it holds that

$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{(2n)!((n+1)!)^2 (n+1)^{n+1}}{(n!)^2(2n+2)!n^n} = \frac{(n+1)^2(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \cdot \big (\frac{n+1}{n} \big)^n$$

$$ = \frac{n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1}{4n^2 + 6n + 2} \cdot \big (1 + \frac{1}{n} \big )^n $$

Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \infty$ and the convergence radius is $\infty$.

What I don't understand is this part:

$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{(2n)!((n+1)!)^2 (n+1)^{n+1}}{(n!)^2(2n+2)!n^n} = \frac{(n+1)^2(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \cdot \big (\frac{n+1}{n} \big)^n$$

Why are there no $n+1$ in the denominator? If we take the binomial coefficient formula, shouldn't $a_n$ be the following?

$$a_n = \frac{(2n)!}{n! \cdot (2n-n)!} \cdot \frac{1}{n^n}$$

And how are the values being cancelled out? I feel like there are some steps I'm missing.
(Also, why is there no tag for radius of convergence?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac {(2n)!}{n!\cdot (2n-n)!}\cdot \frac1{n^n} = \frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2n^n}$$

$$\begin{align}\frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}} &= \frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2n^n}\cdot \frac {((n+1)!)^2(n+1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}
\\&=\frac {(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}\cdot\left(\frac {(n+1)!}{n!}\right)^2\cdot\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}
\\&=\frac 1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\cdot (n+1)^2\cdot(n+1)\left(\frac {n+1}n\right)^n
\end{align}$$

Comment: How does $n! \cdot (2n-n)! \cdot n^n$ lead to $(n!)^2 n^n$?

Comment: $2n-n=n \implies (2n-n)!=n!$

Comment: $n! \cdot n! = (n!)^2$

Comment: Oh, my bad didn't see the faculty, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} =\frac{(2n)!}{n! \cdot n!} \cdot \frac{1}{n^n} \cdot\frac{(n+1)! \cdot (n+1)!}{(2n+2)!} \cdot (n+1)^{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)^3}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n} \right)^n$$